# Set the variation with stock as default variation in Woocommerce variable products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

I have a lot of variation products some of them are out of stock but if i trigger this

Out of stock visibility: Hide out of stock items from the catalog

woocommerce -> settings -> products -> inventory

the variation will get cross mark but the problem is the default variation it will not show anything like images etc.
because the default variation is already have cross mark.

[see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RrtI.png)

[see screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdDLn.png)